# basic condition for multiple request in one action inside a controller - Symfony3

Tags: symfony, controller

I have an autocomplete in Ajax to do with an entity called `Mentor` who can have a `lastName` and a `firstName` which both of them can be autocomplete.
And I need to add two return in my controller function.

here is what I done for one `return` and it works (I did it for `last name`)

```
public function ajaxAutoCompleteMentorAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $lastNames = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Mentor')->getMentorLastAutocomplete($request->query->get('term'));

    $formattedData = array();
    foreach ($lastNames as $lastName) {
        $formattedData[] = array(
            'value' => $lastName['lastName'],
        );
    }
    return new JsonResponse($formattedData);
}
```

Then I tried to do this to add a return for the `firstName` field. like that

```
public function ajaxAutoCompleteMentorAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $lastNames = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Mentor')->getMentorLastAutocomplete($request->query->get('term'));
    $firstNames = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Mentor')->getMentorFirstAutocomplete($request->query->get('term'));

    $formattedLast = array();
    foreach ($lastNames as $lastName) {
        $formattedLast[] = array(
            'value' => $lastName['lastName'],
        );
    }
    return new JsonResponse($formattedLast);

    $formattedFirst = array();
    foreach ($firstNames as $firstName) {
        $formattedFirst[] = array(
            'value' => $firstName['firstName'],
        );
    }
    return new JsonResponse($formattedFirst);
}
```

But I can't make it work. Should I put an `if` somewhere?
thank you for your help

Comment: It has no relation with Symfony. This question should be tagged as `PHP`. It is basic PHP syntax: a function can only return one value. What you could do is combine `$formattedLast` and `$formattedFirst` into one variable and return this combination.

Comment: Then retrurn an array with 2 elements and deal with it with your ajax js code.

Comment: @OscarPerez, thank you for your answer. i'm new in coding, so your solution interest me. How can I combine those two in my controller action? thank you

Comment: It just depends on what are you trying to do. You could, for instance, do: `return new JsonResponse(array_merge($formattedFirst,$formattedLast));` Anyway, I thing you're taking a wrong approach.

Comment: @OscarPerez ok i will try your solution. Maybe I'm wrong, that is why I come here, to find a solution to my problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove both returns and return only:

```
return new JsonResponse([$formattedFirst, $formattedLast]);
```